# Proc Cache Drop Assistance

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2005

We are noticing performance issues with one of our applications.

When the application issues begin the procedure cache size goes from 4.5GB to 0. The plans are then rebuilt and still the application is slow. If I update stats on a key table the issue goes away.

I'm just trying to understand how procedure cache may drop other than `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`?

EDIT: Sorry this is SQL 2005 9.00.4226